# MongoDB left join with nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a model called **Agent.js**

```
id: Number,
  name: String,
  customerInfo: [{
    country: Number, contactNo: String, email:String, Type:String
  }],
```

Each `agent` has a name and multiple `customerInfo` records.

I want to left join **country** with `Country.js` model.

I added this query

```
 const data = await Agent.aggregate([
      { $match: {} },
      { $project: { "id": 1, "name": 1, "customerInfo": 1 } },
      
    ]);
```

[image]

But how do I LEFT JOIN country with the country model?

Comment: you can use `$unwind` and `$lookup` operators.

Comment: Please show a sample of country document too.